# Случайные ветки условий

Tags: массивы, циклы, случайные-числа, условия

Есть 100 слов. Нужно создать предложение из 5 слов. Первое слово берется СЛУЧАЙНО с помощью генератора рандома от 0 до 99. Второе слово определяется с помощью условного оператора IF, но уже не из 100 слов, как было изначально, а берет 10 слов из 100 которые я задаю в условии. Третье так-же. И так далее до 5, пока счетчик слов не станет равен 5 и начнется генерация нового предложения.

Я представил, сколько условий нужно будет написать вручную и ужаснулся. Предполагаю, что есть вариант через цикл или массив, но не особо понимаю, как с ними работать тут. Может кто подсказать в каком направлении покурить тему?

Внизу я привел пример, в котором написаны условия только трех слов. Я намеренно сделал небольшие вариации рандома, от 0 до 2. Но их необходимо сделать множество.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прикрепите код , а не скриншот с кодом , пожалуйста

Comment: И метку языка укажите

Comment: а 3-е слово только от 2-го зависит, или от 2-го и 1-го?

Comment: К сожалению я не могу прикрепить код, так как это не чистый язык программирования, а своего рода программа с готовыми методами. Название Robot Soft Automatic Mouse and Keyboard.

3-е слово зависит от 1-го. При генерации первого случайного числа выбирается одно слово из ста. Далее описаясь на этот рандом происходит новый рандом и выбирается одно слово, уже из 10 и так далее.

Comment: если каждое слово зависит от всех предыдущих, то легче записать все возможные предложения человеком и выбирать N-ное одним рандомом.